# Checking which users and groups has access to file or folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Im trying to write rest to understand which users has access to a certain files and folder.
What REST calls can I use to get which users has access to a file or folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a file you could try the below endpoint:

```
/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Document.docx')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings
```

For a folder :

```
/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Folder1')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings
```

Comment: Looks good and how can I know what permissions they have on the file?

Comment: Just add RoleDefinitionBindings in the end , like this:  $expand=Member,Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings

Comment: On library level I have many users. in the folders I have removed access for many of these. When I run your queries it lists the library level users as well but with limited access. Does limited access mean they do not have access? Any way I can check if a user actually can access the file?

Comment: This REST query is throwing an error like: `Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl`. Remove `/` before "Shared Documents" in relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Use below REST endpoint to get the users who has access to files with their permissions:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/General')?$expand=ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users
```

**Reference**: [How to get permission levels for Files/Folders/Documents in Sharepoint using rest endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264002/how-to-get-permission-levels-for-files-folders-documents-in-sharepoint-using-res)